# astropy.io.fits does not work properly under Python 3

Tags: python, fits, astropy

I have this code:

```
from astropy.io import fits

filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
file = fits.open(filename)
```

When trying to run under Python 2.7, everything works fine. But under Python 3.4 there is this problem:

```
WARNING: An exception occurred matching an HDU header to the appropriate HDU type:  [astropy.io.fits.hdu.base] 
WARNING: The HDU will be treated as corrupted. [astropy.io.fits.hdu.base]
```

After this warning, I'm unable to perform operations on my file. Any ideas how to handle this problem?

Comment: It worked for me in Python 3.4. Share the FITS file on which it fails.

Comment: [Here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qseo78qj9cqilz2/1SWASP%20J194425.22%2B503106.9.fits?dl=0)
It doesn't work for me at all. Here an example file. Funny thing is, it works on python 2.7

Comment: It worked for this file... I believe you need to debug to see what's goes wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know how to do this. Can you give me few tips?

Comment: For a start, wrap the code into [try-catch](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html), so to have additional info on the error. And is it Windows or Linux installation?

Comment: Under ubuntu 14.04. I'm configuring virtualbox right now, so i can check if problem will occur under windows.

Comment: This code is already wrapped by exceptions [here](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/astropy/io/fits/hdu/base.html). Returning warning is executed from exception.

Comment: I have tested both in Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows with Anaconda. Works for me. So, maybe there is a problem in other parts of code.

Comment: it works for me under windows

Comment: What does `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` return?  When passing a string/bytes to `fits.open()`, if it doesn't recognize it as an existing filename on the file system it *might* try to parse it as a FITS file.  If I just download your example file it reads fine, so the issue probably more likely has to do with what you're passing in from `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()`

Comment: `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` is irrelevant. I was checking by running fits.open("file.fits") from simple .py file and it failed as well. Funny think is i switched to debian with fresh python installation and it worked fine.

Comment: Probably should just close the question then.  It doesn't seem to be reproducible.